# Not able to click the WebElement

Tags: java, selenium

I am learning Selenium Webdriver. I am working on one web page where I have to click one button. I wrote the java code below to do that but it is neither showing any exception nor clicking the webelement.

code:
`driver.findElement(By.id("aSaveInfo")).click();`

I have attached the screenshot of the html code. Please help me.[image]

Comment: I think you click the button but it does nothing because of the `javascript:void(0)`

Comment: @MesutGüneş It works when I manually click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience working with an extremely poorly coded, finicky web application, this was often the same problem for me. Try separating it into smaller, more specific actions.

Try this:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement saveinfo = driver.findElement(By.id("aSaveInfo"));
actions.moveToElement(saveinfo).build().perform();
saveinfo.click();
```

Tell me if that works.

Also, does it work when you manually click the button? What @Mesut Güneş said may be very true.

Comment: still I am getting the same issue in other webpage. But when i try clicking manually it works fine.

Comment: @SanjayDVG Does the WebElement change when you mouse over it manually? Does it display it is being hovered over? (color may change, button may "pop", etc..)

Comment: No nothing will change when I mouse over it. Also button will not pop up.

Comment: @SanjayDVG You may want to start another question, with examples of your current script as well as the HTML of the object you are trying to click.